# What substances are good for cleaning a laptop from fat and dirt without damaging it?

Tags: cleaning

All the computer case and peripheral devices surfaces use to get covered with fat-based dirts with time. Also there can be glue left of label stickers and other nasty things. Alcohol can do great cleaning the things but it can also damage the surface coating. What are some solvent liquids safe for plastics and substances used to cover/paint computer appliances?

Comment: distilled water works great. You can use alcohol safely provided you use the correct type.  I should add not "all" cases and devices get covered with fat-based dirts.  Its possible to keep your devices clean with a little effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy one of those laptop/computer cleaning kit that contains a fluid which can remove all sorts of dirts from ure laptop/computer.